# Fade the slideDownMenu on the mouseout using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$("#slideDownDiv").mouseout(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity:"0"
    });
    $(this).css({
        display: "none",
    })
});
```

I have a div named `slideDown` which fadeIn a div named `slideDownDiv` on the mouseover.

The `slideDownDiv` contains 2 other divs, `div a` and `div b`.

`div a` and `div b` each contains an `ul`.

Now I want to fadeout the "slideDownDiv" on the `mouseout`.
But the "slideDownDiv" fades-out when my mouse is somewhere in the middle of the div "the cursor hasn't gone out of the div yet".

Anyone here can tell me why?

Is it because of `slideDownDiv` children??

How can I fix it?

Comment: Probably your "slideDownDiv" does not contain the whole area of what you are seeing. Show us your CSS or a link to jsfiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Dear Tepken..
That's what I thought in the first-place...
To make sure that if my "slideDownDiv" contains the whole area that I want to fade... I've changed the "slideDownDiv" css and made its backgroundColor yellow.... And it did color all the area that I had in mind yellow.... So that's why I have no clue why it fadesaway before I leave the area.

I havent work with jsFiddle .... I dont know how to include jquery library in jsFiddle... AnyWay here is the link:https://jsfiddle.net/e09hoL1k/

Comment: Hey, I suggest you may follow @EdenSource's answer as in this link: https://jsfiddle.net/e09hoL1k/1/. By the way, you can inlude jQuery library in the jsfiddle just at the top left bar

Answer (score 3):

You are using `mouseout` event handler, and it should be `mouseleave` :

```
$('#slideDown').on('mouseover', function () {
    $('#slideDownDiv').stop( true, true ).fadeIn();
})

$('#slideDownDiv').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).stop( true, true ).fadeOut();
});
```

> [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kcdfLmxt/1/)

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseout-and-mouseleave-in-jquery/) is the difference between `mouseout()` and `mouseleave()`

Comment: You're right, but semicolon are not obligatory in JS.

Comment: That's right, just curious if she does not see the result as expected since she's new to jsfiddle. And your answer should be checked as the correct one

Comment: I agree with you. Updated my link with your Fiddle.